# How to use libcurl in C++ Builder

Tags: c++, c++builder, libcurl, vcl

I have download the libcurl  window-generic version for win xp. I am using c++ builder 2007.

I have added the
* curl\include folder in Project->Options->Paths and Defines->[Include path]
* curl\lib folder in Project->Options->Paths and Defines->[Library path]

I have created a simple project with `main.h` as:

```
#ifndef mainH
#define mainH
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#include <Classes.hpp>
#include <Controls.hpp>
#include <StdCtrls.hpp>
#include <Forms.hpp>
#include <curl/curl.h>
#include <curl/easy.h>
#include <stdio.h>
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
class TForm3 : public TForm
{
__published:    // IDE-managed Components
    TButton *Button1;
    void __fastcall Button1Click(TObject *Sender);
private:    // User declarations
public:     // User declarations
    __fastcall TForm3(TComponent* Owner);
};
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
extern PACKAGE TForm3 *Form3;
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#endif
```

and main.cpp as:

```
#include <vcl.h>
#pragma hdrstop

#include "main.h"
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#pragma package(smart_init)
#pragma resource "*.dfm"
//#pragma comment(lib, "C:\Dev\Curl\bin\libcurl.dll")
//#pragma comment(lib, "C:\Dev\Curl\lib\libcurl.a")
//#pragma comment(lib, "C:\Dev\Curl\lib\libcurl.dll.a")
TForm3 *Form3;
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
__fastcall TForm3::TForm3(TComponent* Owner)
    : TForm(Owner)
{
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm3::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
    CURL *curl;
    CURLcode res;

curl = curl_easy_init();
if(curl) {
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://example.com");
    /* example.com is redirected, so we tell libcurl to follow redirection */ 
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1L);

    /* Perform the request, res will get the return code */ 
    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
    /* Check for errors */ 
    if(res != CURLE_OK)
    fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n",
            curl_easy_strerror(res));

    /* always cleanup */ 
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
}
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

When I run the program, I got a linker error as:

```
[ILINK32 Error] Error: Unresolved external '_curl_easy_init' referenced from C:\DOCUMENTS AND SETTINGS\VATISH\DESKTOP\LIBCURLDEMO\DEBUG\MAIN.OBJ
[ILINK32 Error] Error: Unresolved external '_curl_easy_setopt' referenced from C:\DOCUMENTS AND SETTINGS\VATISH\DESKTOP\LIBCURLDEMO\DEBUG\MAIN.OBJ
[ILINK32 Error] Error: Unresolved external '_curl_easy_perform' referenced from C:\DOCUMENTS AND SETTINGS\VATISH\DESKTOP\LIBCURLDEMO\DEBUG\MAIN.OBJ
[ILINK32 Error] Error: Unresolved external '_curl_easy_strerror' referenced from C:\DOCUMENTS AND SETTINGS\VATISH\DESKTOP\LIBCURLDEMO\DEBUG\MAIN.OBJ
[ILINK32 Error] Error: Unresolved external '_curl_easy_cleanup' referenced from C:\DOCUMENTS AND SETTINGS\VATISH\DESKTOP\LIBCURLDEMO\DEBUG\MAIN.OBJ
```

Based on my search I need the `libcurl.lib` file to satisfy the linker but there is no such file in the libcurl installation folder.

Please suggest how it can be resolved.

**Update**: I get `libcurl.lib` using `Borland\RAD Studio\5.0\bin>implib -a libcurl.lib libcurl.dll` and project is not complaining on `libcurl.lib` but now it want `libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll` file ("The application has failed to start because libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll was not found. Re-installing the application may fix the problem" error thrown by BCB).
I have tried download `libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll` file from internet but I got "The application or DLL \Borland\RAD Studio\5.0\bin\libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll is not a valid Windows image."

**Update 2:** I have tried adding `libcurl.lib` both dynamically and statically but still I am facing the same error i.e. "The application has failed to start because libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll was not found. Re-installing the application may fix the problem".

**Note:** I am working on Window XP 32-bit and my application is 32-bit application.

Any suggestion ?

Comment: "but there is no 'libcurl.lib' file in the libcurl installation folder"  probably because you have the libcurl source code and thus you need to compile it to get the lib library file?

Comment: I have updated the question with my progress on the resolution. Please check if you can help me in getting "The application has failed to start because libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll was not found. Re-installing the application may fix the problem" error resolved.

Comment: The linker needs to find lib files. Dynamic libraries are different -- they need to be on the path when you execute the program, or just in the same folder as the program sometimes. Look up static linking vs dynamic linking.

Comment: This is a bit new thing to me. I have tried adding `libcurl.dll` in a project but it didn't help. So how I should do a static linking with `libcurl.dll` (or `libcurl.lib`?) (I know that the #pragma .. Line should be removed as this is dynamic linking)

Comment: I have tried adding `libcurl.lib` file in a project after removing the `#pragma comment(lib, "C:\Dev\Curl\bin\libcurl.lib")` but it didn't help and throws the same error.

Comment: It is clear that you are using a version of `libcurl.dll` that statically links to the 64bit version of OpenSSL. Since you are making a 32bit app, you need a version of `libcurl.dll` that is linked to the 32bit version of OpenSSL instead. This has nothing to do with BCB, and it is not BCB giving you the error, Windows itself is when it tries to load OpenSSL whole loading `libcurl.dll`. Fix your DLLs, you have a mismatch

Comment: I have downloaded the `libcurl.dll` in a package available at https://curl.haxx.se/dlwiz/?type=bin&os=Win32&flav=- . It clearly indicate that the download is for 32-bit window.

Comment: That being said, you might consider a different approach. C++Builder comes with Indy pre-installed, and Indy has a `TIdHTTP` VCL component (which can load OpenSSL dynamically if you need to use HTTPS, which your example doesn't)

Comment: The project I am working on is using an older version of `TIdHttp` and it is not possible for us to upgrade it to the latest version of it. So as an alternative we are looking for using `libcurl` library. The task we have to perform is only possible on latest version of `TIdHttp`.

Comment: What version of Indy do you have, and what task are you trying to do that it can't handle?

Comment: Its Indy 10.1.5 and I am implementing twilio sms.

Comment: @VatishSharma what exactly about Twilio is preventing you from using (an older version of) Indy?

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded a couple of the zip files about a week ago, and have used tdump to look at the dll imports. One of the zip files had imports from the 64-bit libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll file (target CPU type 80386).

I downloaded and tested today and it correctly imports from libcrypto-1_1.dll.

The correct version of the zip file currently has a size 2966Kb in a Windows folder, 2.89Mb in properties and 2.9Mb on the websites.

Note to the wise :- The 32-bit and 64-bit versions have different dll names.

- Win 32 is libcurl.dll
- Win 64 is libcurl-x64.dll